# TimeSpan.ToString("hh:mm") error

Tags: c#, timespan

Why I got an error when I want to get the string of a `TimeSpan` with a custom format.

```
DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString("hh:mm");
// Error: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Comment: remove `TimeOfDay`. just`DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm");` as a side note, it might be ambiguous if the time is beyond 12nn, better have this `hh:mm tt`

Comment: that was an example using DateTime. I have a TimeSpan variable. Check this code: (new TimeSpan(10, 20, 0)).ToString("hh:mm")

Comment: `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString("hh\\:mm");`

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss")
```

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Also regard to use `hh` instead of `HH` for hours, because __HH__ will cause a __FormatException__. It's a pitfall, because for `DateTime` the `HH` is used for the 24 hours format.

Answer (score 27):

According to MSDN TimeOfDay is a TimeSpan. And in the examples of [TimeSpan.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632(v=vs.110).aspx) you see that the `:` needs to be escaped.

> hh\:mm\:ss: 03:00:00

This is also explained on Microsoft's page [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The custom TimeSpan format specifiers do not include placeholder separator symbols, such as the symbols that separate days from hours, hours from minutes, or seconds from fractional seconds. Instead, these symbols must be included in the custom format string as string literals. 
>   For example, "dd\.hh\:mm" defines a period (.) as the separator between days and hours, and a colon (:) as the separator between hours and minutes.

So try:

```
DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString("hh\\:mm");
```

Comment: Oh my god, this example made my day. I just wasted 2 hours reading the docs ignoring the fact that they (breaking ALL world standards as usual) uses backslashes in a format string.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `TimeOfDay`. Directly do `ToString()` on `DateTime.Now`:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm");
```

`TimeOfDay` is a `TimeSpan`. The docs clearly state this about `TimeSpan.ToString(string format)` overload:

*The format parameter can be any valid standard or custom format specifier for TimeSpan values. If format is equal to String.Empty or is null, the return value of the current TimeSpan object is formatted with the common format specifier ("c"). If format is any other value, the method throws a FormatException.*

If you must do it using a `TimeSpan` variable, you can simply add it to a `DateTime` variable that has its time part set to zero, and then use its `ToString()`:

```
DateTime.Today.Add(YourTimeSpanVariable).ToString("hh:mm");
```

Comment: that was an example using DateTime. I have a `TimeSpan` variable. Check this code: `(new TimeSpan(10, 20, 0)).ToString("hh:mm")`